# linked list, where is my logic flawed?

Tags: c++, list, pointers, linked-list, singly-linked-list

so I have of course, looked through a lot of linked list help and all but i can't seem to figure out what is going wrong with mine. I think I understand the logic of other codes, but something is up with mine and I can't get it to work properly.

Code of the function:

```
void SparseM_list::newTerm(valueType newValue, int row, int column)
MatrixTerm *n = new MatrixTerm;
        n->next = NULL;
        n->column = column;
        n->row = row;
        n->value = newValue;
        if (head != NULL)
        {
            cur = head;    
            while (cur->next != NULL) 
            {
                cur = cur->next;
                cout << "does it ever get inside the while loop? cur and curnext -> " << cur << " " << cur->next << endl; <-- never outputs
            }
            cur->next = n;  
        }
        else  //if head is null, n will be the starting point
        {
            head = n;
        }
        delete n;

    }
```

and below is the private struct/variables of my sparse matrix using linked list

```
struct MatrixTerm {
        valueType value; //store value of matrix element
        int column; //store column position
        int row; //store row position
        MatrixTerm *next; //point to next node in the linked list
    };

    MatrixTerm *head; //head point for the linked list
    MatrixTerm *cur, *prev;
```

So basically my logic is this

1. New term information is dynamically allocated to Matrix Term n.
2. If the head is null (which is set by the default constructor), then head = n
3. 2nd set of data goes in. head != Null, so I set cur pointer equal to the head
4. the while loop is skipped for the 2nd data, because head->next should be null and so cur->next should be null. I set the cur->next equal to n
5. 3rd data goes in. Cur->next has n from the previous, so it enters the while loop. Current is set to be cur->next. It checks the while loop condition, and this time, cur->next should be null, so it goes to setting cur->next = n (3rd data set).

However, it never enters the while loop. Where am I messing things up? the while loop is used to traverse through the linked list.

Answer (score 1):

This statement

```
delete n;
```

does not make sense. Remove it.

I hope that initially the data member `head` indeed is set to `NULL` (or `nullptr`).

An alternative implementation of the function can look like

```
void SparseM_list::newTerm(valueType newValue, int row, int column)
{
    MatrixTerm *n = new MatrixTerm { newValue, column, row, nullptr };

    MatrixTerm **current = &head;

    while ( *current ) current = &( *current )->next;

    *current = n;
}
```

If the list allows to append new nodes it would be helpful to declare also one more data member `tail`. In this case a new node will be added to the tail that is more efficient then each time to execute the loop.

Also think about to remove data members `cur` and `prev` and use them as local variables of the methods.

Comment: You are actually assigning the pointer and then you delete it so every time cur->next will point to NULL

Answer (score 0):

You should not `delete n;`, because it will release the memory of your list nodes. You see, you keep push your key into a lock but before open the door you pull out the key...Can you come into the house?

ps, delete the nodes should be held in the desturctor of the list object.